# Why Ajax request duplicate Kendo DropDownList k-list-container on every call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, dropdown

I'm developing an `ASP.NET MVC` Application.

Within the partial, I've my `Kendo DropDownList`:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.MyModel
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId)
    .DataTextField("Description")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCompanies", "WebAPI");
        });
    })
)
```

This is its basic `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return CorrectView("Test");
}
```

Within the Layout, I do some Ajax request on the Server, with a basic `ActionLink`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Ajax Request", "Test", "Partners", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "targetAjax" })

    <div id="targetAjax">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that every time I do a call, it duplicates the `Kendo DropDownList k-list-container`. So if I do 10 request, I'll end up with:

```
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="CompanyId-list" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
```

Which is a problem, since it replicates in the DOM that ID many times.

Is this a common Bug? How can I fix it? Or where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the kendo dropdown list is rendered, in addition to the markup for the visible part of the control, it also creates markup for the pop-up/dropdown/list part of the control.  That is what those "k-list-container k-popup..." divs are.  These divs are appended to the body, *outside* the targetAjax div.

When you replace the contents of the targetAjax, the "old" visible part will get removed and replaced with the "new" visible part *and* a new pop-up will be created.  Since the "old" pop-up is outside the targetAjax div, nothing happens to it unless *you* deal with it as the @Ajax handler has no idea it exists...and you end up with more and more of these orphaned pop-ups.

So, whenever you need to remove an "old" kendo widget you need to perform the clean-up yourself of all the extra markup that is part of the widget using the kendo DropdownList's destroy() method https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/destroy or the kendo.destroy() method https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/destroy
to remove all the extra markup, event handlers, etc.